I couldn't find the cups file in /etc/init.d
I've built a Yocto image for BeagleBone, ensuring to include the cups package in the image recipe. However, after booting the OS, I noticed that the CUPS init script is missing from the /etc/init.d directory.
I would like to understand what might be going wrong and how to ensure the CUPS init script is correctly installed and enabled in my Yocto image.
Since I am very new to yocto and developing in a linux environment, so what is going to wrong please late me know.
I do inside conf/local.conf file add ..
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " cups"
or
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " cups cups-doc"
both also i tried to but same result.
